# Ajax Control Toolkit htmleditorextender AjaxFileUpload Path

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

I'm trying to save an image to a local path (I'm not going to be deploying my project on a server) and I'm having difficulty with putting my finger on the correct path for the file upload:

```
Protected Sub htmleditorextender_ImageUploadComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs)
    Dim fullpath = Request.MapPath("~/img/ar") & "/" & e.FileName
    TextBox1_HtmlEditorExtender.AjaxFileUpload.SaveAs(fullpath)
    e.PostedUrl = fullpath
End Sub
```

This doesn't work, and no image is uploaded to the said folder. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Protected Sub HTMLEditorExtender_ImageUploadComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs)
    Dim fullpath As String = Server.MapPath("~/img/ar/") + e.FileName
    HTMLEditorExtender.AjaxFileUpload.SaveAs(fullpath)
    e.PostedUrl = Page.ResolveUrl(fullpath)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi that code above doesn't seem to work. It seems to be malformed? Is it converted from C#?

Comment: Okay thank you I'll have a look at some other VB.NET examples of DirectCast online as I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Found out what it was! In the client side code: 'onImageUploadComplete' was not set. Duhh! :(

Comment: Debugging would have been useless ehe, the handler wasn't linked! Thank you very much though!